# Detect 404 Error from Appended Script Tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, http-status-code-404, jquery-events

I need to determine how I can detect a 404 error that is being returned from an external script after it appends a script tag to my page.  Here is a breakdown of what is happening.

I am including an external javascript on my page and then calling a method from that javascript to pass certain values which are then used to generate a url path and append a script element to my page with that path as the src. The problem is sometimes the url doesn't exist and a 404 error is being thrown, but when this happens I want a default behavior to occur, but I can't figure out how to subscribe to the response of that external object.

Here is a sample of my html page:

```
<script type="text/javascript"
  src="https://thirdparty.com/AdLoader.js">
</script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>


<!-- This element is where the ad is injected -->
  <div id="AdTargetDiv" style="text-align: center;">
  </div>

<!-- This script requests the ad for the user -->
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
      AdLoader.loadAd({
        api_key:"apikey,
        user_id: "nouser",
        element_id: "AdTargetDiv",
        default_ad_image_url:"https://defaultimageurl.com",
        default_ad_url:"http://google.com"
      })
    });
  </script>
```

And the code for AdLoader.js:

```
window.AdLoader = {
  "loadAd": function(opts){
    var scheme_host = "https://adloader.com";
    if(opts.scheme_host){
      scheme_host = opts.scheme_host;
    }
    var path = "/apikey/"+opts.api_key+"/"+opts.user_id+".js?element_id="+opts.element_id+"&default_ad_url="+opts.default_ad_url+"&default_ad_image_url="+opts.default_ad_image_url;
    var url = scheme_host + path;

    setTimeout(function(){
      var sc = document.createElement("script");
      sc.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
      sc.setAttribute("src", url);

      document.body.appendChild(sc);
    },1);
  }
};
```

The setTimeout function in AdLoader takes the path that was generated and creates a script tag using that source and appends it to my original code so in this example.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://adloader.com/api_key/apikey/nouser.js?element_id=AdTargetDiv&default_ad_url=https://defaultimageurl.com&default_ad_image_url=https://google.com />
```

But since "nouser" is not a valid user, a 404 is returned.

I assumed I would be able to catch a 404 somehow but I'm running into roadblocks. I tried adding `window.addEventListener` for error events but that catches ALL errors on the page and I can't figure out how to parse the event object to find out the type of error and see if it is a 404.

Another thing I tried was to add an event listener to window.AdLoader but I guess that object is not visible to me for some reason. Can anyone point me to a solution? I realize I could build the url dynamically on my own and do an ajax.GET but that seems like a hack to me since the GET is already happening on the page, I just can't seem to figure out how to subscribe to the event and read the error.

Answer (score 0):

If the domain allow CORS or if you are in the same domain you can do something like this:

```
<script>
function testURL() {
  var xhttp;
  var path = "/apikey/"+opts.api_key+"/"+opts.user_id+".js?element_id="+opts.element_id+"&default_ad_url="+opts.default_ad_url+"&default_ad_image_url="+opts.default_ad_image_url;

  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    // code for modern browsers
    xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
    // code for IE6, IE5
    xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(xhttp.status == 404){
       //Page error
    }
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
      //xhttp.responseText contains the page that you get
      //Success do whatever you want
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", path, true);
  xhttp.send();
}
</script>
```